# Windows 10 OpenGL BSOD, "Kernel Mode Trap"

Tags: c++, opengl, bsod

So, I'm building a default context in OpenGL, (Without extensions) and for some reason, as soon as my window opens, I BSOD with an "Unexpected Kernel Mode Trap"

Now, this is pretty default. As I've just used the startup VS 2015 Community win32 application, and applied the OpenGL context code verbatim. Which includes a message box which supposedly should show me my OpenGL version (4.4). However, it opens blank, and upon closing, when it should open the OpenGL CS_DCOWN window, I BSOD.

Just wondering if anyone has insight as to what command is specifically causing the BSOD, or if my practices are wrong?

I come from a mostly Direct3D9 background.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PureGL.h"
#include <gl\GL.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib");

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_PUREGL, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PUREGL));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;    
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);    
    wcex.style          = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PUREGL));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_PUREGL);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        32,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        24,
        8,
        0,
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0,
        0, 0, 0
    };

    HDC ourWindowHandleToDeviceContext = GetDC(hWnd);

    int letWindowsChooseThisPixelFormat;
    letWindowsChooseThisPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(ourWindowHandleToDeviceContext, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(ourWindowHandleToDeviceContext, letWindowsChooseThisPixelFormat, &pfd);

    HGLRC ourOpenGLRenderingContext = wglCreateContext(ourWindowHandleToDeviceContext);
    wglMakeCurrent(ourWindowHandleToDeviceContext, ourOpenGLRenderingContext);

    MessageBoxA(0, (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION), "OPENGL VERSION", 0);

    wglDeleteContext(ourOpenGLRenderingContext);
    PostQuitMessage(0);

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hardware details if known issues - AMD FX 6300, ASUS Radeon R9-285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, `GetDC` should fail, because there's still no client area created for this window - the first window message is `WM_NC_CREATE`, and this is too early for client area manipulation.

You may execute D3D code only after `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: Still, it's pretty lame that there is a BSOD because of this. Shouldn't happen, no matter what.

Comment: WOW. I cannot believe I didn't notice that. I spent so much time restarting my PC and dealing with the BSOD I didn't even think to check order.

Ripped it to the bottom of the main message loop. Works proper. Thanks.